# Buildfire App is not able to retrieve user profile using OAuth token

Tags: buildfire

We have created an App with Buildfire and set that up for using OAuth 2.0 for user authentication.Below is the setup we have done :

[image: Buildfire SSO Setup]

App is able to get token using URL **https://xxxx.us?oauth=token** but when it goes to **https://xxxx.us/oauth/me** for getting user profile it is returning error as **Could not retrieve profile info.**
I have tried figuring out the issue at our end but everything is working fine for us because when I repeated same thing with Postman, I am able to get User profile, below is the reference for that :

[image]

I don't know what's wrong with App, Please help me in resolving this issue.

Edit :
Strangely when I am checking console on buildfire site, I am seeing below :

[image]

which means app is able to retrieve user profile but it stills giving the same error and not allowing user to login into the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have been able to figure out a solution for my problem. If you are using OAuth server from **wp-oauth.com** and user profile can't be retrieved from **https://xxxx.us/oauth/me** then you can try below URL for retrieving user profiles in Buildfire app.

**https://xxxx.us/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me**